# Is there a plugin for Excel import for grails 2.2.0?

Tags: excel, grails, grails-2.2

Is there a plugin for Excel import for grails 2.2.0? I tried to use http://grails.org/plugin/excel-import, but it shows me the following error:

> ...\services\org\grails\plugins\excelimport\ExcelImportService.groovy:
>   4: unable to resolve class org. joda.time.LocalDate @ line 4, column
>   1. import org.joda.time.LocalDate ^ 1 error

Here is the part of BuildConfig.groovy

```
    repositories {

        ...

    mavenRepo "http://repo.grails.org/grails/libs-releases/"
    mavenRepo "http://m2repo.spockframework.org/ext/"
    }
    plugins {
      compile ":excel-import:1.0.0"
      ...
   }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The plugin page says support for Grails 2.0.0+. What does your BuildConfig.groovy look like?

Comment: I have put compile ":excel-import:1.0.0" in BuildConfig.groovy

Comment: Raanan's answer is why I wanted to see exactly what was in your BuildConfig.groovy. Add those two lines if you have not already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `plugins.joda-time=1.3.1` to application.properties and it is working now, I have found the solution here http://jonpolaski.blogspot.com/2013/04/grails-2x-excel-import-via-file-upload.html

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you added the extra dependency repositories:

```
mavenRepo "http://repo.grails.org/grails/libs-releases/"
mavenRepo "http://m2repo.spockframework.org/ext/"
```

to the maven repo section in BuildConfig. Seems like it can't find a dependency it needs (JodaTime in this case)
Hope it helps.

Comment: In fact I have done that and edited my question but doesn't resolve the error.

Comment: Checking the plugin source (https://github.com/jbarmash/grails-excel-import/), it doesn't define the Joda Time dependency, but needs it (ExcelImportService.goorvy). Try adding Joda Time ass a (maven) dependency and see if it works. The LocalDate class is missing, and should be somewhere in the classpath

Comment: Thanks I have found the solution.

Answer (score 1):

just in case of someone need it.
when i was in same trouble on grails 2.4.4 i use 
in my buildconfig: compile ":excel-import:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT"

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following to dependencies to get the jodatime:

```
compile "org.jadira.usertype:usertype.jodatime:1.9"
```

However that still leaves issues with the excel-import:1.0.0

That import uses deprecated classes and won't compile with grails 2.4

There is a version named excel-import:1.0.1 which you can find on Git. Does anyone know how to install that?